# Is document locked after calling findOne and doc.save()

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Im developing an app that uses node-->express-->mongodb-->mongoose.

The app has a concept similar to an auction, where there are bids made and it is very likely that most users will try to make their bid at the last seconds of the auction.

Before users bid is accepted, there is a validation process ( dates, times, bid sizes, users available account balance etc) ,  and once that is done, the bid is accepted and auction document is saved.

The question is, is it possible that users will update the document between 
findOne() call, and a save() call made on the resulting document.

In other words,

```
auction.findOne(_id: "something").exec(function(err, doc) {
    if ( !err && doc ) {
       //use the found document to do some validation that may or may not 
       //take some time.
       //then document validates,
       if ( document is valid ) {
           doc.last_bid = "xxx";
           //is it possible that someone makes an update to the document 
           //here that invalidates the document, and i will end up saving 
           //an invalid document
           doc.save();
       }
       // else -> dont save anything and reject deferred promise.

       //Is it possible that after ive done my validation and document validated successfully, that someone updates it, before i get to call save().
    }
});
```

Is it possible to "lock" a document when making findOne/find query ,and reject any updates to it until im done with using the document ?

Comment: If I understand it well, "on bid", you want to (1) validate the "user account" then, if OK, (2) somehow update the "user account" (temporary lower balance ?) and finally (3) update the "object" to register that new bid ? Or do you only have the  "user documents", and you will recreate the object bid history from that on per need basis ? In any case, don't forget about concurrency issues. By this, I mean potential access to the underlying DB by several _different_ clients _at any moment_. Maybe today there is only one ("the app") but it wouldn't be wise to think it will always be like that.

Comment: Documents i have are,  1)User ( bidder), Item - has a price( most recent bid) , Transactions ( holds user's bids. 
I need to Find the item from db, then check users balance, and create a transaction from user to the item( making part of his account balance as "pending").
Once ive validated everything, created a transaction, i need to finally save the bid. 
The thing is...what if someone else outbid that user during those few hundred milliseconds. I would save a wrong bid as "the highest bid".
I did come up with a more simpler solution, by using findOneAndUpdate, but i need to test that.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can't lock a mongoose document. I propose you a solution, I think that you have a classical problem of "exclussion", so, I will use a mutex to try to access critical section, in your case, "critical section" is udpate mongoose document "doc.last_bid = 'xxx'". Try "locks":
https://github.com/Wizcorp/locks

```
var rwlock = locks.createReadWriteLock();
rwlock.readLock(function () {
    if(document is valid) {
        doc.last_bid = 'xxx'
        doc.set_is_not_valid_or_used = true; // invalidate document => if condition
    }

    rwlock.unlock();
});
```